# Zend framework outputting the letter 'f' onto my page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-feed

I've downloaded the Zend framework stable build (1.11, I believe), uploaded to my servers, and added it to my php include path.

My goal is to use the Feed and Feed_Writer modules to handle some RSS and Atom heavy lifting.

The problem is that whenever I include the Feed_Writer file, I get a random `f` that shows up at the *beginning* of my document.

```
require('Zend/Feed.php');
require('Zend/Feed/Writer/Feed.php');
```

**will** result in the `f`, but **doesn't** throw a fatal when I instantiate a `Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed`

```
require('Zend/Feed.php');
```

will **not** result in the `f`, but **does** throw a fatal when I instatiate a `Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed`

I'm new to the Zend framework, is this some sort of mysterious error code? If so, is there a reference for these sort of things? "Zend f" and "Zend output f" and "Zend echo f" are not particularly google friendly.

**EDIT**

Here is some source that is dumbed down from mine, but still exhibits the error

```
<?php
require('Zend/Feed.php');
require('Zend/Feed/Writer/Feed.php');

$feed = new Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed;
echo 'hi'
?>
```

The output from this is `fhi`

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to **@Drew010** for the answer. Here's the little `f`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8zdM.png]

Comment: Sounds like you have a stray `f` somewhere in one of your files (outside of PHP code).

Comment: do you still get the random `f` when using `require_once(Zend/Feed.php);`? I believe all dependencies are included in the main `Feed` script, so you might be `require`-ing the same file twice. Not sure if that's the case/cause here but it could cause issues

Comment: @Matt, no error message and definitely no stray `f`. I am just starting to play with the framework. The only file that I have it included on is a few lines long and the `f` does not show up until I included the `Zend/Feed/Writer/Feed.php` file. Perhaps Zend has a stray somewhere in all of their includes, but I highly doubt that an enterprise level framework would do that in their stable release.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I do indeed still get it with the `require_once`. I thought the same thing about Feed `require`ing all dependencies, but I noticed that wasn't the case here b/c I get a `fatal` when I try to instantiate a `Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed` unless I include the second file.

Comment: Is it possible you were searching for something in a file, using `ctrl+f` but missed the `ctrl` button, inserting the `f` accidentally?

Comment: @Matt, I'm not catching any errors here, just playing around, so when I try to instantiate a class that doesn't exist it is a fatal error for php and the process exits. `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed' not found`

Comment: Got it. Basically the error has nothing to do with the `f` showing up.

Comment: @wmarbut: If I were you, I'd dump my include paths, check to see if they're set correctly, and include `Zend/Feed/Writer.php` instead, to avoid any future issues. Also, I must say a rogue `f` somewhere in your code is _very_ likely

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I would tend to agree with you, but if you have a look at my edit, you will see that *very* dumbed down source still throws the error for me. I'll output those paths though, that's a good idea

Comment: Delete the ZF source, download a fresh copy and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the only thing in my include path is zend  `.:/web_apps/library`

Comment: @wmarbut: I'm with Tim... I'm looking at the files here, can't see what's causing your problem. Get a fresh copy, check your `phpinfo()` output, and set your ini to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`, if you haven't already

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem a new copy of Zend does the same thing. The source is the same from the edit. I'll try to get an environment to do `E_STRICT | E_ALL` later today. We run some legacy code, so I have to be careful

Comment: @wmarbut, legacy... ouch, `E_STRICT` will spit deprecated warnings all over probably... Might be a long shot, but I just thought of it: are you using `realpath('/web_apps/library')`? Since you're new to zend, also create a new project and look at the index.php file, see how they set up their include paths, might be overkill, but perhaps copy that, see if that has _anything_ to do with that ghost-`f`

Comment: make sure you got the Zend Framework from http://framework.zend.com/download/latest, you just need the minimal unless you want ZendX and Dojo.

Comment: @RockyFord I did get it fromt the framework.zend.com/download/latest address, but I didn't get the minimal one.

Comment: I also am seeing this happening. @wmarbut did you have any luck fixing it? Switching back to an older version of zend fixed it for me.

Comment: @camomileCase, no, but I hadn't tried an older version. I may give that a try later. Thanks!

Comment: @camomileCase we've got an answer now! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is fixed in ZF 1.11.12, there was a bug where an `f` was accidentally placed at the beginning of the file `Zend/Feed/Writer/Deleted.php`.

Bug report is [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12156).  You can safely delete the `f` from the beginning of the file, or use the 1.11.12 release.

Comment: Thank you sir, you'd think that an enterprise framework would have better QC than this.

Comment: :) yea that's quite an unfortunate introduction to the code.  I've been using 1.12 Beta for a few weeks now, it has some other fixes, one that I needed for php 5.4, you may want to check that out as well.

Comment: The 1.11.12 release appears to have the bug as well.