# PHP prints /f from behind the curtains

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail, pchart

I have an old web site which generates PDF reports and sends via email. It uses Zend_Mail, pChart and Zend_Pdf.
I've already noticed that PHP prints out /f somewhere in there, but it is mostly not visible since a new browser tab would only show if the PDF report fails somewhere on the way. Then I would sit with only /f as the output. This made be think it only appeared when there was an error.

This becomes a "problem" when I run this whole generating-mailing procedure using the CLI. It happens when I do something like this:

```
$instance = new $aClassName();
```

It also only happens the first time I do it. Any ideas?

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code. Maybe the innards of the constructor being called.

Comment: There are too many files to give any good examples. I still get the problem when I remove the __construct function though. Is there another function which is called when costructing a class?

Comment: Is it similar to the problem from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11995966/892493)?  I suggest commenting out certain parts of code until you can eliminate the "/f" output and then drill into the code that was commented out and prevented it from showing up.  That or try grepping all of your source files for "/f".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how searched for /f in the beginning of files and found it in more than one file. So there must be some vim command which you are likely to accidentally press, which inserts /f.

It was not me who wrote them though, but I know the guy used vim as an editor.